# Sql query to exact matches of the word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is like this

```
declare @searchWord varchar(100)
set @searchWord = 'carb9' 
declare @tableWord varchar(100)
set @tableWord = 'Racing Carb9 uretor'
--set @tableWord =  'carb9'

select 1 
where  @tableWord like '%[^a-z0-9]' + @searchWord + '[^a-z0-9]%'
or @tableWord like @searchWord + '[^a-z0-9]%'
or @tableWord like '%[^a-z0-9]' + @searchWord
```

This query works when @tableWord is 'Racing Carb9 uretor' but doesnt work when @tableword is just 'carb9' . It should work in both condition . What i am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: If you enclose @tableWord in spaces you do not need `or`s because there will always be non-word characters before and after any word in text: `where ' ' + @tableWord + ' ' like '%[^a-z0-9]' + @searchWord + '[^a-z0-9]%'`.

Answer (score 2):

You could add condition `@tableWord = @searchWord` to your query. At the moment, none of your conditions could return true for that case

```
declare @searchWord varchar(100)
set @searchWord = 'carb9' 
declare @tableWord varchar(100)
set @tableWord = 'Racing Carb9 uretor'
--set @tableWord =  'carb9'

select 1 
where  @tableWord like '%[^a-z0-9]' + @searchWord + '[^a-z0-9]%'
or @tableWord like @searchWord + '[^a-z0-9]%'
or @tableWord like '%[^a-z0-9]' + @searchWord 
or @tableWord = @searchWord
```

Answer (score 0):

@tableWord='carb9' will not match any of the pattern of your where clause,